Unable to receive props from Parent Element
Have a parent component Products and another component SingleProduct.
I am trying to pass a product as a prop to SingleProduct but getting undefined when I console.log.
Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?
Also tried passing the props using UseState but still getting undefined.
import data from "../data"

const Products = () => {
    const products = data;

    return (
        <div className='pt-12 grid gap-4 md:grid-cols-2 lg:grid-cols-3 '>
            {products.map((prod) => {
                return (
                    <Link to={`/product/${prod.id}`}>
                        <SingleProduct product={prod}></SingleProduct>
                    </Link>
                )
            })}
            <Link to='/home'></Link>
        </div>
    )
}

export default Products

const SingleProduct = ({ product }) => {
    console.log(product)

    return (
        <div>
            <figure className='px-4 pt-4'>
                <img
                    src={prod.image}
                    alt='Elf'
                    className='rounded-xl h-64 md:h-48 w-full object-cover'
                />
            </figure>
        </div>
    )
}

export default SingleProduct

App.jsx
const router = createBrowserRouter([
  {
    path: '/',
    element: <Products></Products>,
  },
  {
    path: '/product/:id',
    element: <SingleProduct></SingleProduct>,
  },
])

function App() {
  return (
    <RouterProvider router={router}></RouterProvider>
  )
}

export default App


Did you console.log your data before passing to see if it's not undefined?

You are not getting the product when you are clicking on the link and redirect to /product/id?

Yes link is working and I get sent to localhost:5173/product/1. There I get no image just 'Elf' alt text. On the console.log I get undefined for props.product

You are using the SingleProduct component twice.
First time you are mapping the products inside Products component and creating links that has SingleProduct inside them and then passing the prod to the component which is fine.
But for the second time you are using this component as an element for the /product/:id path where you don't pass any product to it which means the product is undefined.
What you can do is to make another component just for the route that shows inside the /product/:id and then import data and then find data based on the id of the URL like this:
const SingleProductPage = () => {
let { id } = useParams();
const [product, setProduct] = useState();

useEffect(() => {
  id && setProduct(data.find((prod) => prod.id == id))
}, [id]) // runs whenever the id changed and updates the product

return product ? <SingleProduct product={product} /> : null
}

export default SingleProductPage;


Thanks Ali, when I added the new page above it worked for the Single Product. But when I went to products page and clicked on a product I got undefined reading image. Which is weird because on the console.log i am getting the data at top of console and undefined below it. Is it how I am passing props in my projects component? Should I be using useState there too?

Just to add I did update my App.jsx  path: '/product/:id to 

It is happening because at first the product state is undefined and then inside the useEffect we are getting the product and the product is undefined in the meantime so it gives us error but if you render the component after we get the product everything will be ok
